# Xamarin Forms Shell Textcolor in Android Modal is not applied

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Shell Application in which I open several pages as Modal. I would like to set the bar text color to a chosen value so, that you can actually read the text in the dark and the light theme. This is the navigation code:

```
        return shell.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(page)
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            BarTextColor = Color.Red
        });
```

(Red is only as an example to clearly be able to see the color change).
On iOS the color is adjusted as expected:

[image]

But on Android the color stays always white:

[image]

Comment: I test it in my demo, it work as normal in android, you can refer to this GIF. https://imgur.com/a/dMwUFwf  And I update my demo to you, you can test it in your device. https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/XAnimals.zip

Comment: Please check if you have styles in `style.xml` file.

Comment: I checked your sample and I can confirm that the title color is adjusted. but the menu buttons are not unfortunately.

Comment: I update answer, you can refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `styles.xml` file, add `<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ff0000</item>` in your `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar` style.

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangeDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    
    <!--<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fb2b32</item>-->
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ff0000</item>
  </style>
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]